# Batch file - code to edit a string between strings in a dtsconfig / xml file

Tags: batch-file

I have written a batch file to replace certain strings in a dtsConfig file.
Now from what I can gather, batch cannot directly edit dtsconfig files so a workaround I'm using which works is 
to convert the .dtsConfig files into .xml first, edit them, and convert them back.

However I have a lot of .dtsconfig files with several different strings i want to change

e.g. the string SERVER_NAME

`<ConfiguredValue> Data Source=SERVER_NAME;Integrated Security=True;</ConfiguredValue>`

My code below is able to change the SERVER_NAME value but instead I would prefer to change the contents between
Data Source=    and ;Integrated Security. so that I could do it for a lot of dtsConfig files that might have different server names

Is this possible with batch?

This is my code below:

```
@echo off > *.xml
setLocal DisableDelayedExpansion
```

:: make a copy of the .dtsConfig files
set str="C:\dtsconfig\copyArea"

:: Copy all dtsConfig files into the backup directory
xcopy "*.dtsConfig" %str1% /E /I

:: Rename all .dtsConfig files to .xml to enable batch to work with them
ren *.dtsConfig *.xml

:: set the new server name
set dataSource=NEW_SERVER_NAME

@echo off > ConfigFile.dtsConfig
setLocal DisableDelayedExpansion

if exist ConfigFile.dtsConfig del ConfigFile.dtsConfig

for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%G in (ConfigFile.xml) do (
    set str=%%G

`setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

:: set the string "SERVER_NAME" to be the dataSource defined above
set str=!str:SERVER_NAME=%dataSource%!

:: generate a new dtsConfig file with the rename in place
>> ConfigFile.dtsConfig echo(!str!
endlocal)`

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this instead of your current replace loop.

It checks every line for the string "Data Source", if it found the string split the line into a head "... Data Source" and a tail ";...", effectivly remove the old part of the Data Source.
Ex.
`<ConfigValue> Data Source=SERVER_NAME;Integrated Security=True;</ConfigValue>`
splits to
`head=<ConfigValue> Data Source`
`tail=;Integrated Security=True;</ConfigValue>`

```
@echo off
setLocal DisableDelayedExpansion
set "dataSource=NEW DATASOURCE"
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%G in (ConfigFile.xml) do ( 
    set "line=%%G"
    setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    REM set the string "SERVER_NAME" to be the dataSource defined above
    set str=!str:SERVER_NAME=%dataSource%!

    set "newLine=!line:*Data Source=!"
    if !newLine! NEQ !line! (
        call :length lenNew newLine
        call :length lenLine line
        set /a headLen=lenLine-lenNew
        for %%n in (!headLen!) do (
          set "head=!line:~0,%%n!"
        )
        set "tail=!newLine:*;=!"
        set "newLine=!head!=%dataSource%;!tail!"
    )

    REM generate a new dtsConfig file with the rename in place
     (echo(!newLine!)
    endlocal
)
goto :eof

:length <resultVar> <stringVar>
(   
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    set "s=!%~2!#"
    set "len=0"
    for %%P in (4096 2048 1024 512 256 128 64 32 16 8 4 2 1) do (
        if "!s:~%%P,1!" NEQ "" ( 
            set /a "len+=%%P"
            set "s=!s:~%%P!"
        )
    )
)
( 
    endlocal
    set "%~1=%len%"
    exit /b
)
```

Btw. It isn't a good idea to use the `::` comment style inside of parenthesis blocks, as lables works different in blocks, better is to use `REM`.

```
(
echo 1
:label1 & echo invisble
:label2 & echo visible
echo 2
)

(
echo 3
:label1 creates a syntax error, befor the block executes

echo 4
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort you put into that.

Comment: Note however, your code along with mine, depend on knowing beforehand the SERVER_NAME each time for each dtsconfig file, in otherwords for the line  <ConfiguredValue>Data Source=SERVER_NAME;Integrated Security=True;</ConfiguredValue> the following the charachters before and after SERVER_NAME would be the same in each dtsconfig file but SERVER_NAME might be different if you get me?

Comment: @Stephen: The SERVER_NAME is not important in my example, because all characters between the `=` and the `;` are replaced with the new `%dataSource%`